# asp.net - download files in specific folder

Tags: asp.net

i'm trying download files that is located in specific folder. I'm using this code, but it gives me an error in `Reponse.End();` -> Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack

```
if (m.Path.EndsWith(".txt"))
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/txt";
            }
            else if (m.Path.EndsWith(".pdf"))
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            }
            else if (m.Path.EndsWith(".docx"))
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/docx";
            }
            else
            {
                Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
            }
            string nameFile = m.Path;

            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + nameFile);

            Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IMAGESPATH"]) + nameFile);
            Response.End();
```

I also tried `Response.Write`, but it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Response.End` will throw ThreadAbortException and it's there only for [compatibility with old ASP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end.aspx) and you should use [HttpApplication.CompleteRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest.aspx)

here is the example :

```
public class Handler1 : IHttpHandler
{    
  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
  {
    context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=pic.jpg");
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
    context.Response.TransmitFile(context.Server.MapPath("/App_Data/pic.jpg"));
    context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
  }

  public bool IsReusable
  {
    get
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: now has no error, but also does nothing. does not download the file.

Comment: strange, I tried that code in ashx handler and works OK, updated my answer with that example. Are you serving that from handler ?